# osmdroid mapview: Layout changes when zooming in

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

i'm currently experimenting with a osmdroid mapview.
My XML layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text1"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text2"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/osmmapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This looks quite fine when executed and works very well:
[image: Pic]

Unfortunately there is a problem with the layout if the zoom in button is hit, as then the 2 TextViews are disappearing for the duration when the zooming in is executed:

[image: The layout is looking like this during the zooming process]

After the zooming it's again normal, as shown on the first screenshot.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your layout like below:

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/osmmapview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

A View with width and height set to "fill_parent" fills the entire screen.

Comment: If i do so the OSM map isn't shown anymore. It's all just black where the map should be

Comment: And if you try: `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"` ?